# Building Java Library that Depends on Android Project Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I have an Android project that defines various datatypes that are serialized via Protocol Buffers. I would like to have a separate Java project that is able to deserialize these data types on the server.

My project is structured as follows:

```
Android Library
  - Data
      - TypeA 
      - TypeB
      - ...

Java Server
  - Parser (depends on .Data)
```

In this example, all classes in the package Data handle marshaling themselves.

When trying to build the Java Server, it successfully compiles the Android project, but ultimately fails with Gradle saying it cannot find the referenced packages.

Note, that I can successfully build the Java Server with cross project dependencies if I only pull in other Java libraries, leading me to believe this is a Java -> Android dependency problem rather than a Gradle configuration issue.

On possible solution I have considered is to pull out all of these data types from the Android project and place them in a separate Java library. The trouble with this however is that some of these classes merely provide a means of converting Android specific classes ( SensorEvent, Location, etc ) into a type that can be used with ProtoBuf. One solution I've been considering would look like this:

```
Data Types
  - TypeA
  - TypeB
  - ...

Android Library
  - Data
    - AndroidTypeA (Class with Android Specific constructor that can be cast to the parent type)
    - AndroidTypeB
    - ...

Java Server
  - Parser ( Depends on the Data Types module )
```

While this would indeed solve my issue, it hardly seems like the best solution.

Is there any way to accomplish this through Gradle alone?

---

For reference here are abbreviated versions of my `build.gradle` files.

Android Library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.bar.androidlib"
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'
}
```

Java Server:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'
    compile project(':androidlib')
}
```

**Edit:**

Specifically Gradle gives the following error:

> error: package com.foo.bar.androidlib does not exist

Comment: You mentioned "but ultimately fails with Gradle saying it cannot find the referenced packages.". Can you give us more info about the failure?

Comment: "Is there any way to accomplish this through Gradle alone?" -- I doubt it. I fail to understand why the Java server code has any dependency on `Data`. I'm no protobuf expert, but off the cuff I would think that it should *only* have a dependency on the `.proto` files. Just because your server happens to be written in Java does not mean that there should be any greater coupling between the client and the server. After all, if your server was implemented in any other programming language, you would not have that server depend upon Java classes used by the client.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, I am attempting to send over some data received from instances of things like SensorEvent. I have a datatype that can be serialized with Protobuf that can be constructed with a SensorEvent.

Comment: @MikeLaren Specifically, the error is: error: package com.foo.bar.androidlib does not exist. Android Studio can find these packages no problem, and it is able to first compile them, but during linking it runs into trouble.

Comment: "I have a datatype that can be serialized with Protobuf that can be constructed with a SensorEvent" -- so? Protobuf is an interface definition. Your Android code is welcome to use that interface definition and code generators to create classes that can be populated by `SensorEvent`. Your server code is welcome to use that interface definition and code generators to create classes that can do whatever your server is looking for. The only shared elements are the `.proto` files.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well I've encapsulated the logic to create a `TypeA` from a protobuf message in `TypeA` itself. The problem comes occurs when TypeA can also be constructed with something like SensorEvent etc. I'd rather not have to rewrite the code to build and read a protobuf message with every change. I've ended taking the route I described in my question, and have convenience constructors on the android side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Gradle, you can't have a Java library that depends on an Android library. This is because the Android plugin in Gradle isn't based on the Java plugin and isn't compatible with it, so Java doesn't understand its sourcesets and can't otherwise play nice with it.

I don't think you can solve this problem purely through Gradle configuration, and even if you could, it would probably make your build wickedly complex and fragile. Your best bet is to have your Java stuff rely only on Java stuff, isolating out the common protobuf dependencies there, and have the Android side depend on Java. You outlined an approach with Android versions of some of the classes; that may work, but I don't know enough details about what you're doing to comment on it in detail.

Comment: Would it recognize it as a Java project if you declare both `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and `apply plugin: 'java'`?

Comment: No, it gets mad if you try to apply both plugins.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, the refactoring was relatively painless, and I've resolved the problem for now. Thanks!